# Set auto scroll to bottom in fix height table

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a table with fixed height and i am adding rows with javascript. My problem is once it reach the scroll. Scroll is set at top and i can't see the newly add row. I want scroll to move down as row added.

I tried this working in Firefor and chrome but not working in IE8.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('button[id^="product"]').click(function () {

              var newTr = $('<tr></tr>');

                newTr.html('<td width="29px" style="text-align:center;">x</td><td width="144px">Product 1</td><td width="44px" style="text-align:center;">2</td><td width="86px style="text-align:right;">16.50</td>');

                newTr.appendTo("#saletbl");

         var tableElement = document.getElementById('saletbl');

         tableElement.scrollTop = tableElement.scrollHeight;
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use div. You can put your table into div. You can also switch off the horizontal scroll bar if you want to only show vertical scroll bar.

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;horizontal-scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
```

Use 
    -ms-overflow-x:hidden

in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus to the last row of the table after appending row, by replacing this

```
var tableElement = document.getElementById('saletbl');

     tableElement.scrollTop = tableElement.scrollHeight;
```

to this

```
$("#saletbl tr:last-child").focus()
```

Comment: Add table inside a div and set css style `overflow: auto`